# Open raw audio with avformat_open_input

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, libavformat

I want to fill ffmpeg.formatCtx for `raw(LINEAR16,48000khz)` audio file using `avformat_open_input()`.

I've tried to pass own `AVInputFormat`, but not suceeded in it.

This is how i used to open file.

```
std::string fn = "file:" + this->file.path;
int r = avformat_open_input(&ffmpeg.formatCtx, fn.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
```

Tried to find needed format with `av_find_input_format(`), but not succeeded to0.

Without input format ffmpeg determines file as `mp3`.

**Is there convenient way to do such case?**

Comment: The values for sample size, type, byte order, frequency, etc are not stored in a raw audio stream and therefor ffmpeg has no way of reading them out. You must manually set my them in the codec context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main things that gets done in avformat_open_input are:

- Allocate memory for AVFormatContext and fill AVFormatContext.
- Tries to guess the input file format, codec parameter for the input file.

Because you only have raw audio data, you need to allocate memory for AVFormatContext and fill AVFormatContext by yourself.

Otherwise, the raw audio data don't need to demux and decode, I think you should not use avformat_open_input.